# Нужно сделать маску для ввода email на чистом JS вида _@_._

Tags: javascript

Задача: Нужно сделать маску для ввода email на чистом JS вида *@*._
Нельзя использовать JQuery и другие библиотеки.
Может у кого есть готовый код или пример, долго пытался сделать и не получилось.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
         <p>E-mail</p>
    <input id="email" type="text" >
    <script>
        //код для маски
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

если есть пример работы похожей маски с библиотеками, тоже будет полезно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Советую прочитать вот эту статейку https://habr.com/ru/post/175375/

Comment: [готовый плагин](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) [готовый плагин 2](https://imask.js.org/)

Comment: @Егор Трухан, регулярки для проверки и маска это совсем разное